# I want find way Ubuntu live USB with large Persistent Storage

Tags: ubuntu, usb, storage, live, persistent

I am new start about this program.
My Work is setup system, build system and benchmark with Deeplearning and Bitdata server system.
my Problem is " I want make Ubuntu 18.04 4 LTS version Live USB with Large Persistent Storage."
but It has limited with 4.3gb at exFAT3 version. (my USB size is 64GB with USB 3.0)

I changed foramt version NTFS. but this is not find device in server.

I need install Python 3.7.0 version, Cuda10, Cudnn, Tenserflow and many CNN for deeplearning TEST and benchmark.
this all is over 4GB.

so I was search some website.
but I can't find any method. :(

Can you help me? I need your help.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I was struggeling with nearly the same issue and found out that new versions of Rufus (https://rufus.ie/) can create large persistent partitions (tried it with 6 GB).

Maybe you have to switch to a newer version of Ubuntu:
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/08/rufus-creating-persistent-storage-live.html